# SwiftUI: Are .slide and .move transition animations broken?

Tags: swiftui

It seems that `Transition.slide` and `Transition.move` animations are broken. Using `AnyTransition.slide.animation()` does not animate. It requires an additional `.animation()` modifier. This is a problem, since often I want to animate only the slide and nothing else.

Here is a demo. The goal is to have a sliding animation *without* animating the black ball. The `.scale` and `.opacity` animations work just fine. But `.slide` and `.move` either do not animate, or they animate the black ball.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screens: [Color] = [Color.red]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(screens.indices, id: \.self) { i -> AnyView in
                let screen = screens[i]
                
                return AnyView(
                    Screen(color: screen)
                        .zIndex(Double(i))
//                         Try uncommenting these lines one by one. The scale and opacity animations work fine. But move and slide animate only when the additional .animation modifier is uncommented below.
//                         This is a problem, since uncommenting the standalone .animation modifier, also animates everything inside the Screen() view, which is not what I want.
                        
//                        .transition(AnyTransition.scale.animation(.linear(duration: 2)))
//                        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.linear(duration: 2)))
//                        .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading).animation(.linear(duration: 2)))
                        .transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(.linear(duration: 2)))
//                        .animation(.linear(duration: 2))
                )
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Text("Screens Count: \(screens.count)")
                
                Button("prev") {
                    removeScreen()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                
                Button("next") {
                    addScreen()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
            }
            .zIndex(1000)
        }
    }
    
    func addScreen() {
        let colors = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.yellow]
        
        screens.append(colors[screens.count % colors.count])
    }
    
    func removeScreen() {
        guard screens.count > 1 else { return }
        screens.removeLast()
    }
}

struct Screen: View {
    static var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 25
    static var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 - 25

    var color: Color
    @State var offset = CGSize(width: Self.width, height: -1 * Self.height)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 50)
                .offset(offset)
        }
        .onAppear { offset = CGSize(width: Self.width, height: Self.height) }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any thoughts how to use `slide` and `move` animations without animating everything else inside the view?

Comment: Another bizarre thing, is that adding `.animation(nil)` before `.transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(.linear(duration: 2)))` disables the transition animation. Whereas logically it shouldn't, since it's placed before. The only way I can get slide transition animating and the black ball not animating is to put `.animation(nil)` inside Screen view right after `Circle().offset(offset)`. This is a poor solution, since there can be hundreds of potentially animatable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a solution. It's not perfect, but it's workable. Putting a view inside a `NavigationView` somehow separates `.animation` modifiers:

```
struct Screen: View {
    static var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 25
    static var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 - 25
    
    var color: Color
    @State var offset = CGSize(width: Self.width, height: -1 * Self.height)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                color
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 50)
                    .offset(offset)
            }
            .onAppear { offset = CGSize(width: Self.width, height: Self.height) }
            .animation(.none)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```